# Message on my server

Tags: server

I just logged onto one of my servers and one of them has picked up the message:

Mon Apr 17 13:42:11 UTC 2017: Data received from /xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is ♥  +&à
Cookie: mstshash=hello

I also received the same message yesterday at 15:23 from the same ip.  Iv had the exact same cookie sent from another ip address so i was wondering what it was.

Answer (score 5):

microsoft remote desktop - compromised windows machines attempting to connect to any remote desktop destination port (3389 typically) open on other machines.